# How to reference other tag in usage guidance?

Tags: support, tags, tag-wiki

[Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/) has had a rather strange problem. There is a tag called [content-security-policy](/questions/tagged/content-security-policy), which is about a specific mechanism in modern browsers.

However, many users have used this tag for questions about any kind of policies, such as policies in their company. For this purpose, the tag [corporate-policy](/questions/tagged/corporate-policy) was created.

In order to prevent confusion, I wanted to edit the "usage guidance" section of both tags to clarify something akin to:

> Use this tag for *[this thing]*. For *[the other thing]*, use [that-other-tag](/questions/tagged/that-other-tag).

However, since markdown is disabled in the usage guidance, what is the correct way to reference another tag there?

Comment: I tend to use `[other-tag]` but I'm not sure if that convention is followed by everyone

Comment: here is a rough SEDE query that allows you to check usage of certain tag formats: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1090038

Comment: @rene Seems to be a somewhat accepted form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always use square brackets [] to indicate other tags. A usage guidance / tag wiki excerpt might then look something like this:

> For questions about biting as a form of violence, e. g. how to make a child stop biting others or themself, why they bite or at what age this behavior usually occurs. For questions about chewing, use [eating]. For questions about habits like nail biting, use [habits].

(This is for tag [biting](/questions/tagged/biting), referencing other tags [eating](/questions/tagged/eating) and [habits](/questions/tagged/habits).)